# How can ı login instagram via c#

Tags: c#, ajax, authentication, instagram

I try to log in to Instagram using c# but there one thing that ı can't solve.

When ı look at the login ajax request, ı can see username and enc_password but ı have no idea about how to create an enc_password field in c#.

**enc_password** looks like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7soog.png

ı have some solutions for other languages but ı can't convert c#
https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api/issues/1010

What should ı do? Thx for helping.

Comment: This is a hashed (and probably salted) password. You can use a library like BCrypt to get a password like this, from a normal string.

Answer (score 1):

enc_password contains: encryption version, unixtime and base64 encoded string with aes-256-gcm encryption. Cipher contains additional data (time), thats why Ashish Sharma function is not the same and not solve your issue.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow! Please visit the [help] to familiarize yourself.